# lightning-progress-indicator doesnt change the current step color on click of the Step

Tags: lightning-progressindicator

I have used lightning-progress-indicator of path type. Where I am dynamically assigning steps. When i hover or Focus the Step it changes the step color to selected stage color but as soon as I remove the Focus(mouse pointer) from the step it removes the selected step color.[image]

I want once I click the step its color should remain as selected stage (darkblue)[image] till i click any other step or button.

In standard opportunity path component when we click any stage it assigns it current stage color and remains as  it is until we click 'Mark as Current Stage' step button or until we reload page.

Code

```xml
<template>

    <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={currentstep} type="path" variant="base">
        <template for:each={options} for:item="step">
            <lightning-progress-step label={step.label} value={step.value} key={step.label} onstepfocus={handleclick}></lightning-progress-step>
        </template>
        <template if:true={showcurrentstage}>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Mark As Current Stage" title="Mark Current Stage" onclick={handlecurrentupdate} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </template>
        <template if:true={showcompletestage}>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Mark Stage As Complete" title="Mark As Complete"  onclick={handlecomplete} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </template>
    </lightning-progress-indicator>

</template>
```

Comment: Please add your JS code to the question.

Comment: Please find githublink https://github.com/meghani0669/MyProjects

Comment: Hi Pooja, I understand that you're new here so I'll help you with how you should ask questions: in order to maximize your chances of receiving an answer, please provide just the right amount of code embedded directly in your question (not a link in comments).

Comment: Hi POZ,  i need to remove extra javascript code and will put it here...Basic requirement is if we are using progress indicator tag which is in built...exact previous step doesnt get highlighted on click of it. but previous to previous steps get highlighted